# Reviewing a paper with suspiciously good results

Tags: cheating, peer-review

I'm currently reviewing a paper which deals with iris recognition, submitted to a top conference in the field of biometrics. The paper's main contribution is a recognition model that, while presented as novel, is in fact essentially a very simple convolutional neural network.

However, in the experimental section the method is compared to several state-of-the-art approaches (including deep CNNs) and while the state-of-the-art achieves 70-80% accuracy, the method from the paper gets close to 100% accuracy. In addition, the methods were tested in 2 scenarios, first with 50 identities, then with 100 to recognise from. All the state-of-the-art methods performed worse in the 100-identity case (as expected), however the paper's method actually saw a slight increase in the performance accuracy.

This to me smells fishy, to put it mildly. However, there are 2 considerations:

1. Technically it is possible (however improbable my experience in the field says this is), that the simple approach just handles this specific problem that much better than the deeper convolutional networks.
2. Even if the experimental work was devised improperly, this may not have been done with ill intent. Simple mistakes in the training/testing procedures (such as training the model on the testing data) could conceivably cause such a discrepancy, without malicious intent on the authors' part.

To put it bluntly, I intend to reject the paper, however I would like to do so without making either direct or implied (possibly unwarranted) accusations of misconduct on the part of the authors.

How I have currently addressed this particular issue in my review (listed next to other shortcomings of the paper):

> In the experimental section it is unclear how the models were trained. How was the data split into training, validation, testing data? Did all the trained models (including the [redacted] model) use this same data split in their training? In my experience a (near-)100% accuracy is unlikely to be achieved, regardless of the chosen recognition method, when the dataset is difficult enough that state-of-the-art methods (like [redacted]) only get 70-80% accuracy. Oftentimes such unnaturally high accuracy points to a mistake in the training/testing process (such as testing on previously-seen data). The fact that the performance *improves* from the 50-category case to the 100-category case, rather than dropping off as it (understandably) does for the other approaches, makes this even stranger. I would suggest the authors either publicly release the training/testing data and the code used, or provide enough detail in the experimental section to make these results directly reproducible.

Is this an appropriate way to address such results? Should I confer with the conference editor on this and voice my concerns to them directly?

Comment: Is it possible to request code? In my field I never let papers be published without code, but we are primarily journal based, rather than conference based.

Comment: On your point #1: provide concrete reasons why their results cannot be better than X.   Then ask for a response.  Personally, I hate reviewers who said that they 'feel' that the paper is wrong or not novel without providing hard evidences.

Comment: @IanSudbery I did request the code in my response. I agree that the research code should always be available to facilitate reproduction of the results, and this is the standard we follow in our research group. Unfortunately, however, this is not (yet) standard practice in the field.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus I agree with your point. I also have provided proper references and argumentation for the lack of novelty in the paper in my review. However, the main reason for this question is precisely what you touch on: I cannot conclusively prove that their results are impossibly good with the information I have.

Comment: @MatedeVita I would say, "I do not believe the results are correct.  Can you please provide the main reason that allows X to beat Y?'.  Also if you know of a fundamental problem, then you can ask the authors, 'how did you go faster than the speed of light?'

Comment: If the dataset is experimental, does the paper rule out the possibility that the high accuracy is just a random variation? 100 categories is not many.

Comment: Rather than a rejection your current report seems to suggest a major revision. Perhaps the authors can sensibly answers your points. This is general. Of course if you are sure that certain things cannot happen is different. But "unlikely" it is not a solid base for rejection in itself.

Comment: "close to 100% accuracy" -- curious, *exactly* what is the claimed accuracy rate?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins it was 99.0% with 50 categories, up to 99.3% in the 100-category case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response already seems exceptionally well-crafted to me; it is non-accusatory but also sets out the reasons that the results appear strange.  I wouldn't change a thing about your statement.  I also doubt it is necessary to confer with the the editor on the matter, because your written response is clear and does not require supplementary explanation.  Good work.

Answer (score 10):

If it's technically possible but unlikely to be correct, in my opinion the best option is to request major revisions asking for more details and results, such as evaluating the model on new datasets, providing the code and trained model to the reviewers, etc. It's good to be skeptical, but it is weird to outright reject a paper that you believe *might be* correct without making sure that it really is incorrect. In other words, if you submitted a paper with a surprising result, would you want the reviewers to reject it simply because they are surprised, without determining why it is wrong?

> Is this an appropriate way to address such results? Should I confer with the conference editor on this and voice my concerns to them directly?

For most journal submission sites, there are comments sent to the authors, and comments for the editor only. The latter is a good place to send comments to the editor. You could also email the editor directly if the journal submission site does not provide for private comments.

Comment: I probably should have clarified that the rejection is not based solely on the reported results, but rather on the lack of novelty, the presentation, scarcity of prior research surveyed, and the lack of comparison on external databases in the experiments. My question wasn't so much about whether to reject or accept the paper but more so on how to address my doubts about the reported results in the review. I also got a second opinion today from my supervisors and they were in agreement that the paper in its current form was nowhere near appropriate for this conference.